# Date picker in rails is working for chrome but not for Firefox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have listed files below. application.js is also properly set

```js
$('#data_1 .input-group.date').datepicker({
  todayBtn: "linked",
  keyboardNavigation: false,
  forceParse: false,
  calendarWeeks: true,
  autoclose: true
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id="data_1">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">DOB</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6 input-group date">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </span>
    <%= f.text_field :dateofbirth,class: 'form-control datepicker', autofocus: true %>
  </div>
</div>
```

it gives only static picker which can not be modified. application.js and application.css is set by flow. In chrome it works but not in firefox.

Comment: Have you checked the console messages(logs) on Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a javascript compatibility issue. Open up Firebug in Firefox and look at the logs, it should display any errors.

I suggest using jquery's datepicker which comes included in Rails:
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Code snippet from JqueryUI:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</body>
</html>
```